# how to get total score as a sum of two two score values in neo4j or cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4jclient, cypher-3.1

I have tried the following query to get total score (score is in array of string like ("5","2")) as sum of home score and away score game.

```
match (e:Epl), (e1:Epl)
where ((e)-[:AWAY]->(e1) or  (e1)-[:HOME]->(e)) and e.home=e1.away
return e.home,e1.away,
sum(toInteger(e.score[0])+ toInteger(e1.score[1])) as totalScore
```

I do have the relationship between two nodes as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThmhB.png)

I want to calculate total score for each team (sum of home score and away score)

Comment: You mentioned what you have tried, but what is the problem with the results? What would you like to get as a result?

Comment: From your image, it looks like for every outgoing :HOME relationship, there's an incoming :AWAY relationship. If this is so, then I'd recommend simplifying your model, and just using a single relationship, since you can infer the other easily. It would also simplify your query. If every outgoing :AWAY is paired with an incoming :HOME and vice versa, then you're performing quite a lot of redundant expansions that may be slowing your query.

Comment: Also, do arrays always have two elements? If so, it would make sense to use simple properties instead (e.g. `homeScore`, `awayScore`).

Answer (score 0):

As an optimisation (to avoid creating a Cartesian product), it's beneficial to specify the `-[:AWAY|HOME]-` relationship, which allows either `AWAY` or `HOME` types in any direction. The `WHERE` clause then takes care of checking the direction of the relationship.

```
match (e:Epl)-[:AWAY|HOME]-(e1:Epl)
where ((e)-[:AWAY]->(e1) or (e1)-[:HOME]->(e))
  and e.home = e1.away
return
  sum(toInteger(e.score[0]) + toInteger(e1.score[1])) as totalScore
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance but the query you have suggested provides total scores of all teams. However, I have wanted to get  a total score for each individual team.